# SQL Server using Powershell with encrypted Passwords

Tags: sql-server, powershell, encryption

I am trying to extract the File Size(MB), Space Used(MB), Free Space(MB), Log File Size(MB), Log Space Used(MB), Log Free Space(MB), DB Free Space for an instance of SQL Server as part of a Health Check for my company.

I am trying to achive this using a function and encrypted password as below.
I create a Encrypted Password using the Code below: -

```
$password = "testdev"
$secureStringPwd = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
$secureStringText = $secureStringPwd | ConvertFrom-SecureString 
Set-Content "D:\PowerShell\EncryptedPassword.txt" $secureStringText
```

I have then created a Function which would then extract the data from a SQL Query stored in a certain path. The problem is when i execute the code within the function, it executes without any issues. However with the Function I get no data

```
    Function Get-SpaceAvailableInSQLServer
    {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param ( )

    $FilePath = "D:\PowerShell\"
    $FileName = "SQLServerInfo"
    $FileExtn = "htm"

    $pwdTxt=(Get-Content 'D:\PowerShell\EncryptedPassword.txt')
    $user = 'windev'
    $securePwd = ($pwdTxt | ConvertTo-SecureString)

    Import-Module "sqlps" -DisableNameChecking
    $tableData = Invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $DBName  -Username $user -Password $securePwd -InputFile $SQLfilename
    $tableData |
        Select-Object -Property `
        @{label="DB Name"; Expression={($_.Dbname)}},
        @{label="DB Status"; Expression={($_.dbstatus)}},
        @{label="Recovery Model"; Expression={($_.Recovery_Model)}},
        @{label="DB Size"; Expression={($_.DBsize)}},
        @{label="File Size(MB)"; Expression={($_.file_Size_MB)}},
        @{label="Space Used(MB)"; Expression={($_.Space_Used_MB)}},
        @{label="Free Space(MB)"; Expression={($_.Free_Space_MB)}},
        @{label="Log File Size(MB)"; Expression={($_.Log_File_Size_MB)}},
        @{label="Log Space Used(MB)"; Expression={($_.log_Space_Used_MB)}},
        @{label="Log Free Space(MB)"; Expression={($_.log_Free_Space_MB)}},
        @{label="DB Free Space"; Expression={($_.DB_Freespace)}} 
  }
Get-SpaceAvailableInSQLServer | convertto-html D:\PowerShell\SQLServerInfo10.htm
```

**Error**

```
Invoke-sqlcmd : Login failed for user 'windev'.
At D:\111747\PowerShell\SQLServer\Get-SpaceAvailableInSQLServerInstance WIP.ps1:17 char:22
+         $tableData = Invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $DBName  -U ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExectionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Invoke-sqlcmd : 
At D:\111747\PowerShell\SQLServer\Get-SpaceAvailableInSQLServerInstance WIP.ps1:17 char:22
+         $tableData = Invoke-sqlcmd -ServerInstance $server -Database $DBName  -U ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParserException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

**Sample Data Required**

```
DB Name  DB Status  Recovery Model  DB Size     File Size(MB)    Space Used(MB)    Free Space(MB) 
-------  ---------  --------------  -------     -------------    --------------    -------------- 
master   ONLINE     SIMPLE             6.44              4.44              3.69              0.75 
model    ONLINE     FULL              16.00              8.00              2.31              5.69 
msdb     ONLINE     SIMPLE            30.69             16.00             12.69              3.31 
tempdb   ONLINE     SIMPLE           584.00            576.00             55.81            520.19
```

Comment: Why not use trusted authentication?

Comment: Does not work in my company. Guess it&#39;s blocked. Moreover, I would want to know if I select the inside of the function it executes fine but as a function it gives me the error as mentioned in my query

Comment: And the credentials you're using are for an SQL User, not a Windows or Domain User?

Comment: Trusted Authentication can't be blocked.

Comment: Yes that would be correct, the credentials are For a SQL user authentication and not for windows or domain authentication.